# Why doesn't --limit-modules work for me?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

I have the following program:

```
package org.example;

import com.google.common.primitives.Ints; // This is a guava class

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] __) {
        System.out.println(Ints.class);
    }
}
```

When I run this program as an automatic module, everything is fine:

```
> java -p myapp.jar;guava.jar -m myapp/org.example.Example
class com.google.common.primitives.Ints
```

But when I use `--limit-modules`, the program is still running fine:

```
> java -p myapp.jar;guava.jar --limit-modules myapp -m myapp/org.example.Example
class com.google.common.primitives.Ints
```

Should not there be something like:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/primitives/Ints
```

?

Comment: I believe while computing the module graph the module is still resolved... By the way, you didn't get a command not found error with that one? Shouldn't it be `myapp.jar:guava.jar`? (colon in tool, semicolon in docs) :)

Comment: @nullpointer I'm on Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Limiting-the-observable-modules): "The effect of this option is to limit the observable modules to those in the transitive closure of the named modules plus the main module, if any, plus any further modules specified via the --add-modules option."

In the question then initial module is an automatic module. Automatic modules are resolved "as if" they require all observable automatic modules. This is why `--limit-modules myapp` is the equivalent of `--limit-modules myapp,<all-automatic-modules>`.

Comment: I knew it was there, just couldn't hold that much of source of truth ;) Just curious, could the `--show-module-resolution` help here as well? Should it be insisted to be used?

Comment: @AlanBateman `guava` is not in the transitive closure of `myapp`. So how can it be working as specified?

Comment: @Alan Does the update in answer mean, if the `guava.jar` is removed from the initial module path, the `NoClassDefFoundError` would start appearing in the question context?

Comment: Yes because the guava module will not be resolved and so none of the types in the module will be visible.